# Federated Auth Sitecore Editor and Public site without Identity Server

Tags: federated-authentication

Sitecore 9.3

I have Okta federated auth working great on the public site. But I am trying to get the sitecore editors to log in, I can never get access for their users. Does Sitecore require a separate url for CM and delivery for federated login? It works fine with Identity Server, but I am trying to get away from IS.

And I am never able to get Okta to show up in the login screen

[image]

After I log in, I am an admin and in an editor role, but I get access denied to the content editor (/sitecore). If I go to /sitecore/admin I get a looping login.

[image]

Here is the config

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
    <sitecore>
      <settings>
        <setting name="Foundation.Identity.Okta.ClientId" value="XXXXXXX"/>
        <setting name="Foundation.Identity.Okta.ClientSecret" value="XXXXXX"/>
        <setting name="Foundation.Identity.Okta.Authority" value="https://Client.okta.com"/>
        <setting name="Foundation.Identity.Okta.OAuthTokenEndpoint" value="/oauth2/v1/token"/>
        <setting name="Foundation.Identity.Okta.OAuthUserInfoEndpoint" value="/oauth2/v1/userinfo/" />
        <setting name="Foundation.Identity.Okta.OAuthRedirectUri" value="XXXXXXXX"/> 
        <setting name="Foundation.Identity.Okta.ApiKey" value="#{mysite.OktaProvider.ApiKey}" />
        <setting name="Foundation.Identity.Okta.LoadBalanceDNS" value="XXXXXXXX"/>
        <setting name="Foundation.Identity.Okta.AccessDeniedUri" value="/Access-Denied"/>

      </settings>
      
      <pipelines>      
        <owin.identityProviders>
          <processor type="Sitecore.Foundation.Okta.OktaIdentityProvider, Sitecore.Foundation.Okta" resolve="true" />
        </owin.identityProviders>
        <!-- 
          Pipeline to handle OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotification AuthorizationCodeReceived event / callback. 
        -->
        <Okta.AuthorizationCodeReceived>
          <processor type="Sitecore.Foundation.Okta.Pipelines.Okta.AuthorizationCodeReceived.MapClaims, Sitecore.Foundation.Okta" resolve="true" />
        </Okta.AuthorizationCodeReceived>

        <!--<owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn>
          <processor type="Sitecore.Foundation.Okta.Pipelines.owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn.FillUserProfileFacet, Sitecore.Foundation.Okta"
                     patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.CookieAuthentication.SignedIn.CleanupUserProfile, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication']"
                     resolve="true" />
        </owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn>-->

        <startTracking>
          <processor type="Sitecore.Foundation.Okta.Pipelines.startTracking.FillUserProfileFacetTracker, Sitecore.Foundation.Okta" 
                     patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.ExperienceExplorer.Analytics.Pipelines.StartTracking.ApplyExplorerModel, Sitecore.ExperienceExplorer.Analytics']"
                     resolve="true" />
        </startTracking>
      </pipelines>

      <federatedAuthentication type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
        <identityProvidersPerSites hint="list:AddIdentityProvidersPerSites">
          <mapEntry name="Client" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Collections.IdentityProvidersPerSitesMapEntry, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true">
            <sites hint="list">
              <site>Client</site>
            </sites>

            <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
              <identityProvider ref="federatedAuthentication/identityProviders/identityProvider[@id='Okta']" />
            </identityProviders>

            <externalUserBuilder patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultExternalUserBuilder, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication']" type="Sitecore.Foundation.Okta.Providers.UserBuilder, Sitecore.Foundation.Okta" resolve="true">
              <param desc="isPersistentUser">true</param>
            </externalUserBuilder>
          </mapEntry>
        </identityProvidersPerSites>

        <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
          <identityProvider id="Okta" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.DefaultIdentityProvider, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" >
            <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
            <param desc="domainManager" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseDomainManager" resolve="true" />
            <caption>Log in with Okta</caption>
            <icon>/assets/okta.png</icon>
            <domain>Clienttech</domain>
            <transformations hint="list:AddTransformation">
              
              <transformation name="everyone access" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultTransformation,Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
                <sources hint="raw:AddSource">
                  <claim name="groups" value="SG-ClientCentralSitecoreAdmins" />
                </sources>
                <targets hint="raw:AddTarget">
                  <claim name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" value="Clienttech\editor" />
                </targets>
                
                <keepSource>true</keepSource> 
              </transformation>

              <transformation name="admin access" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultTransformation,Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
                <sources hint="raw:AddSource">
                  <claim name="groups" value="SG-ClientCentralSitecoreAdmins" />
                </sources>
                <targets hint="raw:AddTarget">
                  <claim name="http://www.sitecore.net/identity/claims/isAdmin" value="true" />
                </targets>
                
                <keepSource>true</keepSource> 
              </transformation>

              <transformation name="map contributor role" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultTransformation,Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
                <sources hint="raw:AddSource">
                  <claim name="iss" value="https://Client.okta.com" />
                </sources>
                <targets hint="raw:AddTarget">
                  <claim name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" value="Clienttech\webuser" />
                </targets>
                
                <keepSource>true</keepSource>
              </transformation>

              <transformation name="fullname" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultTransformation,Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
                <sources hint="raw:AddSource">
                  <claim name="name" />
                </sources>
                <targets hint="raw:AddTarget">
                  <claim name="FullName" />
                </targets>
              </transformation>
              
            </transformations>
          </identityProvider>
        </identityProviders>

      </federatedAuthentication>
      <oktaSettings>
        <oktaFieldMappings type="Sitecore.Foundation.Okta.Models.OktaFieldMapping, Sitecore.Foundation.Okta">
          <fieldMappings hint="raw:AddItem">
            <field name="UserCode" OktaFieldName="oktaCode" />
          </fieldMappings>
        </oktaFieldMappings>
      </oktaSettings>

    </sitecore>
  </configuration>
```

Comment: Can you add to your question setup of Login/Logout redirect URIs and Initiate login URI from Okta?

Comment: Thanks @PeterProcházka I finally got it working late last night. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I had the identity server disabled by breaking the url to the identity server in the config file `Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.config`. My fix was to enable to config file `Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.Disabler.config.example` (just remove the example). This completely disables the identity server and allow federated auth load right. I dont see any examples of anyone else doing that, but it worked.

That file contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--

Purpose: This include file disables Sitecore Identity authentication.

-->
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/" >
    <sitecore>
        <federatedAuthentication>
            <identityProviders>
                <identityProvider id="SitecoreIdentityServer">
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </identityProvider>
            </identityProviders>
        </federatedAuthentication>
        
        <sites>
            <site name="shell" set:loginPage="/sitecore/login"/>
            <site name="admin" set:loginPage="/sitecore/admin/login.aspx"/>
        </sites>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```